# How to deploy a modular Sinatra app to Heroku?

Tags: static, heroku, sinatra, public

For some reason, I can't access any files in the public dir. Not found error. I'm not putting the `public` part in the URL, obviously.

View the [Lovers source code repository on GitHub](https://github.com/mattdipasquale/loversapp.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sweet. I fixed this. After reading about [Sinatra Configurations](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html), I added this line to my application class:

```
set :root, Lovers.root
```

That worked!