# Sinatra static assets are not found when using rackup

Tags: ruby, configuration, sinatra

I have a simple Sinatra app that is configured using the modular style. When I start the app using `rackup -p 4567` as recommended in the readme file, the static assets in the public folder are not served. But when I start it using `shotgun ./config.ru -p 4567` then they are served. Why does this happen? Could this happen in production?

Here is my code:

```
# config.ru
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
require 'sinatra'
require 'jammit'

Bundler.require
Jammit.package!


require File.expand_path('./stick.rb')
run Stick
```

and this is the app ruby file

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Stick < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    haml :index
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like there are two good answers to this one (neither of the existing ones worked for me).

First off, in your config.ru file, you can include the following:

```
# Replace the directory names to taste
use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/stylesheets', '/javascripts'], :root => 'public'
```

Alternatively, if you're running your app via rackup, the `:static` option is set to `false` by default. You can remedy this by the following incantation:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :static, true
  # ...
end
```

Comment: From [Sinatra docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__enabledisable_static_file_routes): `The :static setting is enabled by default when the public directory exists.` The second method didn't help me running with Thin.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and i solved like this.
I have added this line in my config.ru .

```
map "/public" do
  run Rack::Directory.new("./public")
end
```

And i use the static files in my views like this

```
%link{:type => 'text/css', :rel => 'stylesheet', :href => '/public/css/reset.css'}
%link{:type => 'text/css', :rel => 'stylesheet', :href => '/public/css/text.css'}
%link{:type => 'text/css', :rel => 'stylesheet', :href => '/public/css/960.css'}
%link{:type => 'text/css', :rel => 'stylesheet', :href => '/public/css/app.css'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not positive, but you may need to `set :root, Stick.root`?

(Based on [How to deploy a modular Sinatra app to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989711/how-to-deploy-a-modular-sinatra-app-to-heroku))

Answer (score 2):

In order for me to get this working on a new Sinatra app launched via config.ru, I had to do two of the things suggested in the other answers:

```ruby
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :static, true
  set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

First create a folder named "public" in your sinatra project, then add a couple of folders

- stylesheets
- javascripts
- images

Add your CSS, JS and or JPG,PNG (images) to each folder

Finally as @sirfilip says add below lines to config.ru file

```
map "/public" do
 run Rack::Directory.new("./public")
end
```

If generic Sinatra (no framework default)

views/layout.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/your_file.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/your_image.ico" />
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
...
<script src="javascripts/your_js.js"></script>
```

views/index.erb

```
      <div class="margin-bottom-30">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="badge">42</span></a></li>
              <li>...</li>
            </ul>          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

All of you images, stylesheets and javascripts will be available for any url registered in your Sinatra app , problem solved!