# Sinatra App doesnt load Imges on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra

My Sinatra app loads the images fine on Localhost but not when I deploy it to Heroku. I have a Public folder and then an img folder under that where all the images are stored. In the erb file I have

```
<img id="monkey" src="/img/photo1.jpg" alt="test" >
```

and in the css section on the erb file I have

```
background: url(/img/photo1.jpg)
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: The problem is that those URLs are being mapped to whatever routes are in your application.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055489/sinatra-static-assets-are-not-found-when-using-rackup  Use google before posting here.  I'm surprised this even works on your local machine though.

Comment: @SirUncleCid I added the     map "/public" do run Rack::Directory.new("./public") end to my config.ru but still doesn't work on Heroku :(